# WordPress plugin changes install directory when deleted and reinstalled

Tags: php, wordpress

Embarrising enough, I created this particular plugin. Works great, but in testing, this happens:
1. Install plugin via WP Dashboard zip installer.
1a. Works great; fully functional.
2. Deactivate & delete files via WP Dashboard.
3. Reinstall plugin (#1 above).
- Issue: In the theme's plugin folder, a sequential number is appended to the plugin's folder, e.g. "my-plugin" becomes "my-plugin1"

This is a very light weight plugin, only loads a form, script, CSS file, shortcodel. - no SQL tables, no user settings, etc.

Any ideas? I've never repeatedly installed, removed, then reinstalled a plugin, so this is a new thing for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I've had this happen to me before when the plug-in files haven't been completely removed properly. Try manually checking/deleting in your FTP and it should then work correctly...

Comment: Ah, okay. Still weird. This is a quick fix; after a reinstall, I FTP'ed, changed the dir back (deleted the "1"), re-activated the plugin, all set. I just worried about support stuff as I've submitted the plugin to the Repository.

Comment: I think it happens if something goes wrong with the deletion part in WordPress, I always found it happened when I deleted my plug-in and then tried to re-install it almost immediately... I have had my plug-ins on the repository a few months now with over 10,000 downloads and it has never been a reported issue, so I think you should be fine and if it does happen to someone you know what to tell them to fix it.

Comment: Okay, cool, correct, this occurred from quickly deleting then immediately reinstalling the plugin. I did not add an uninstall script, since it's only the files that need to go. I thought the "append 1 to foldername" might be a server catching issue. If so, maybe it times out. Server side stuff is not my game, so I really don't know.

Comment: Potentially this could be the case in terms of caching on your server side... that would certainly be my first guess, but like you server stuff is not my strong point.